# Django not receving telegram webhook

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

I am trying to build a telegram bot. I am using django application for it. I hosted my django application it is working fine. I am running on pythonanywhere server with https. I successfully set my web hook and it is working completely fine. But I don't know why my django server is not receiving any responses. This is my views.py code

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import requests

@csrf_exempt
def telegram_bot(request):
    # print(request.GET)
    # print(request.POST)
    print("this is sample")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<id>&text=this is a sample text')
return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I am just printing some sample message to my log and sending a sample message back to the telegram to the corresponding chatID. But this code is not getting triggered, I am not sure why this is happening.

Finally, I tried this 
    https://api.telegram.org/bot/getWebhookInfo

It is displaying me about 22 messages are not sent yet in pending_update_count.

Any help is acceptable, thanks

Comment: Check your access and error logs to make sure that the request is making it to your web app.